# dict（list）TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
words = [] 
for word in df.head(1000).values: 
    words.append(word)
```

The words is[['phone', 422],['good', 374]]

When i use

```
dict(words)
```

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable

```
type(words)
list
```

I think words is a list.So what could cause this error?

Comment: It seems you assigned a DataFrame to the name `dict`.

Comment: what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you need [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`Series.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html) if need generate dict from columns `A` and `B`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['phone','good'],
                   'B':[422,374]})

print (df)
       A    B
0  phone  422
1   good  374

#test if similar output of my sample df
words = [] 
for word in df.head(1000).values: 
    words.append(word) 

print (words)
[array(['phone', 422], dtype=object), array(['good', 374], dtype=object)]
```

---

```
print (df.set_index('A')['B'].to_dict())
{'phone': 422, 'good': 374}
```